# XML context grepping

Tags: grep, xml

Below is the contents of my file,

```
<A>
<number>100</number>
<name>Word1</name>
</A>
<A>
<number>101</number>
<name> Word2</name>
</A>
```

if I grep for `Word1`, I'm trying to see the output as below,

```
<A>
<number>100</number>
<name>Word1</name>
</A>
```

if I grep for `Word2`, I'm trying to see the output as below,

```
<A>
<number>101</number>
<name>Word2</name>
</A>
```

Someone could help with this please ?

Comment: Need a help in shell scripting

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: Will it always be formatted so you can just keep 2 lines before and 1 after? If not, are there other constraints on how it is formatted? If not, you'll probably have to use an XML parser. But if so, then this can likely be done with `grep` or a related tool. Also, are you limited to using features of `grep` that are [required by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/), or are you willing to use extended features provided by your `grep` implementation? If you're willing to use extended features then what OS is this and what does `grep -V` show? *Please **[edit]** with details.*

Comment: Have a look at [xmlgrep](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xmlgrep).

Comment: I tried the below command, which gives me the output what Im expecting, but I need some better code, even the format of the content is changed...

grep -A1 -B2 Word1 Filename

Comment: ↑ that's good information. Please [add it to your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/405982/edit)

Answer (score 9):

If this is part of a well formed XML document you can extract the required part with an XML parser.

To satisfy the *well formed* requirement, I've wrapped your XML fragment with `<root>` and `</root>`.

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -c '//A[name="Word1"]' -n file.xml
```

If you cannot satisfy this directly, you can wrap it explicitly

```
( echo '<root>'; cat file.xml; echo '</root>' ) | xmlstarlet sel -t -c '//A[name="Word1"]' -n
```

In either case, the output is this:

```
<A>
<number>100</number>
<name>Word1</name>
</A>
```

Comment: Note that it wouldn't work for `Word2` because of the extra space before it in the sample. Note that it still outputs an empty line if there's no match. `xmlstarlet sel -t -m '//A[name="Word1"]' -c . -n` or `xmlstarlet sel -t -m '//A[contains(name,"Word2")]' -c . -n` may be better.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I was hoping that leading space was a typo. (Yes, yes I know...) BTW why `-m '//...contains()' -c .` rather than `-c '//...contains()`?

Comment: See also `xmlstarlet sel -t -m '//name[contains(.,"Word2")]' -c .. -n` for the parent of `name` nodes that contain `Word2`.

Comment: `-c //... -n` outputs an empty line if there's no match. `-m //... -c . -n` doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

With `pcregrep`:

```
<file.xml pcregrep -Mo '(?s)<A>(?:.(?!</A>))*Word1.*?</A>'
```

With GNU `grep`:

```
<file.xml grep -zPo '(?s)<A>(?:.(?!</A>))*Word1.*?</A>' | tr '\0' '\n'
```

(though that means the whole file is loaded in memory and assumes it doesn't contain NUL bytes).

Some PCRE operators:

- `(?s)` turns on the `s` flag (`.` matches even line delimiters)
- `.(?!</A>)` any character provided it's not at the start of `</A>`.
- `.*?` non-greedy version of `.*`
- `(:...)` just grouping.

It's fooled by things like `<![CDATA[</A>]]>` or wouldn't find a `Word2` expressed as `<![CDATA[W]]>ord2>` or `&#87;ord2` for which you'd need a XML parser. But then a XML parser would need valid XML input which your sample is not unless you enclose it in a top-level element, would need to read the file in full (but then again that's generally your lot when working with that format) and would potentially transform the content (expand the `<![CDATA` and some `&...;` sequences). And an xpath expression would make it difficult to find those `Word1` anywhere including in comments or XML tags or attributes.